# css in separate file overidden by firefox internal html.css, but works embeded in html head

Tags: css

I have a .html.slim file, where in the head has

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
```

if I add the following style in this .html.silm file, it will work

```
style
  | ul {list-style-type: none;}
```

But if I put it inside the "application.css", css will not working. The firefox inspect element shows it is overridden by

```
:-moz-any(ol, ul, menu, dir) :-moz-any(ol, ul, menu, dir) ul square
```

Even if I attach !important, still not working

Can anyone suggest how I can solve this problem

Comment: use reset css like this https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6